# fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/VSchool/event-workbook.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Tags: visual-studio, terminal, submit

Can can tell me whats wrong and what's the solution I have tried everything nothing work .fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/VSchool/event-workbook.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403

Comment: Please see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63636504/how-to-change-github-local-repo-git-config-credentials-to-circumvent-403/63647344#63647344

Answer (score 0):

You should remove your git credentials by going to `Control Panel\User Accounts\Credential Manager` (if you are on Windows) and then sign in again when requested by the CLI.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are in the .git/ directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Before writing an answer, please take the time to carefully read and understand the question. If you have any doubts or questions about the details of the problem, consider leaving a comment to ask for clarification. This will help ensure that the answers provided are accurate and useful.