# How to change Github local repo .git/config credentials to circumvent 403?

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code, credentials

I'm trying to push to my remote Github repository from my work PC that has other credentials set up and this is what I get:

```
remote: Permission to *** denied to ***.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/***': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I tried changing `.gitconfig` but it didn't help.

I suspect VS code is somehow remembering the work credentials but I'm unable to find where is it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer [here](https://intellipaat.com/community/11832/pushing-to-git-returning-error-code-403-fatal-http-request-failed). At the end, it wasn't about resetting VS code credentials.

Find `.git/config` file under your repo directory and under section `[remote "origin"]` change the url from

`https://my-username@github.com/my-username/my-repo.git`

to

`ssh://git@github.com/my-username/my-repo.git`.

After that, I was able to push upstream with no problems. I don't quite understand why, but it works.